# vstest executionengine error pdbs missing

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, mstest, vstest

I'm running VS2013 premium and it's built-in testing engine. Earlier today is started throwing the following errors for any test. I've tried re-starting VS bu that didn't help, any ideas?

```
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.x86.exe'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Utilities.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Measurement\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Measurement.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.GenericTestAdapter.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.MSAppContainerAdapter.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.UnitTestFramework.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.MSPhoneAdapter.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.OrderedTestAdapter.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.TfsLogger.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.TmiAdapter.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.TrxLogger.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.VSTestIntegration.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.ComInterfaces.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.CppPhoneUnitTestExtension.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.Composition\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.CppUnitTestExtension.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 2): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.VSTestIntegration.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Loaded 'C:\Workspaces\BTS.GO.FactFeeds\More2.Tests\bin\Debug\More2.Tests.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.BizTalk.TestTools\3.0.1.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.BizTalk.TestTools.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\More2.Helper\v4.0_1.0.0.0__f21081c0e8e00ef1\More2.Helper.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
A first chance exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestFramework.TestFailedException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.VSTestIntegration.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestFramework.TestFailedException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.VSTestIntegration.dll
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 2): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Unloaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Unloaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.VSTestIntegration.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Unloaded 'C:\Workspaces\BTS.GO.FactFeeds\More2.Tests\bin\Debug\More2.Tests.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.BizTalk.TestTools\3.0.1.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.BizTalk.TestTools.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\More2.Helper\v4.0_1.0.0.0__f21081c0e8e00ef1\More2.Helper.dll'
The thread 0x2cf8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.Core.dll
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.Core.dll
The program '[11432] vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following a reboot - problem resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Restart Visual Studio was sufficient for me.