# MStests taking too long to load

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest

I have a project setup to use MSTests but they are simply taking too long to load all the the test DLLs, before even loading my project specific DLLs.

I´m on Visual Studio Professional 2015 with Resharper 10.0.1

I´m attaching only part of the the logs down here since stack overflow complaint about limit, but it would be 10 times as bigger, following the same line of these dlls. The total time was around 30s, before my dlls started being loaded, but only a couple of acceptable seconds afterwards.

Is there anyway to optimize this?

EDIT:

Actually, found that some libs are being loaded/unloaded multiple times under different "domains"( which I have no clue of the meaning up to this point)

```
(CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 16): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled. 

(CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 16): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'

(CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 17): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089‌​\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

Edit2:

The pattern I described above is happening a lot of times. Searching for **mscorlib.dll** on the logs I found **138** matches!!

My hunch is that this is the cause, but I still have no clue of the solution

Thanks

```
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.x86.exe'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Measurement\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Measurement.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Utilities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.GenericTestAdapter.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.MSAppContainerAdapter.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.UnitTestFramework.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.MSPhoneAdapter.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.OrderedTestAdapter.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.TfsLogger.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.TimelineLogger.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.TmiAdapter.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.TrxLogger.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.VSTestIntegration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.ComInterfaces.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.CppPhoneUnitTestExtension.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.Composition\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.CppUnitTestExtension.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WEB TOOLS\DNX\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.UnitTest.TestAdapter.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\JFPTI2GP.J4J\PowerShellTools.TestAdapter.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Interfaces.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Management.Automation.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop\7.1.40304.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\PYTHON TOOLS FOR VISUAL STUDIO\2.2\Microsoft.PythonTools.TestAdapter.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.PythonTools.Analysis\v4.0_2.0.2.2015__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.PythonTools.Analysis.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\PYTHON TOOLS FOR VISUAL STUDIO\2.2\Microsoft.PythonTools.VSInterpreters.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\EnvDTE\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\EnvDTE.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop\7.1.40304.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0\v4.0_14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.10.0\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.10.0.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.14.0\v4.0_14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.14.0.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\Microsoft.PythonTools.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio - IronPython\2.2\Microsoft.PythonTools.IronPython.Interpreter.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio - Uwp\2.2\Microsoft.PythonTools.Uwp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\PresentationCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.9.0\9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.9.0.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
```

Comment: Seems similar to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784883/vstest-executionengine-error-pdbs-missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784883/vstest-executionengine-error-pdbs-missing).

Comment: Ha that would be funny, I´ll try it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually, after some research I found out that the main culprit was the usage of TestSettings1.testsettings instead of test.runsettings.

After a bit of time adapting the tests, (mostly due to the lack of Global DeploymentItems, which I solved using a base class), the tests are now running under 10s which is way better.

Think there´s still room for improvement though, but I´m at least satisfied for now