# VsTest.ExecutionEngine keeps load - unload dll's

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, mstest

I started to face a strange problem without me doing any change.
This topic describes it the best, but no solution worked for me. It can take more than 20 minutes, and still not finishing the load-unload:

[MStests taking too long to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36562071/mstests-taking-too-long-to-load?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I tried restarting the computer, repair VS installation, but nothing helps!
The only think I noticed is that when I remove the .testsettings file, then it takes 2 minutes and then it starts the test. However, I don't want to not use .testsettings file, and can't understand what's the problem.

Also, when I inspect the deployment folder of the test under TestResults, then I see it slowly copies my project dll's there.

Can someone help with this ?

Comment: Looks like it's trying to execute the tests in parallel.Which will cause the assemblies to be loaded into multiple application domains to prevent interference when touching static members. Usage of `testsettings` is deprecated, you should really switch to `runsettings`. The performance os test execution, especially parallel has improved dramatically with VS2017 15.3+

Comment: Do you know why it is trying to execute the tests in parallel ?
It isn't configured at the test settings.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/10/10/parallel-test-execution/